# How to calculate md5 checksum on directory with java or groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, directory, md5, checksum

I am looking to use java or groovy to get the md5 checksum of a complete directory.

I have to copy directories for source to target, checksum source and target, and after delete source directories.

I find this script for files, but how to do the same thing with directories ?

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

def generateMD5(final file) {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    file.withInputStream(){ is ->
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]
        int read = 0
        while( (read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
    byte[] md5sum = digest.digest()
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum)

    return bigInt.toString(16).padLeft(32, '0')
}
```

Is there a better approach ?

Comment: You should use one of the `org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex` methods in preference to the code above

Comment: I find FastMD5, really easy to find file MD5 : String hash = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(new File(filename)));
More easy to use and more Fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a function to calculate MD5 checksum on Directory :

First, I'm using FastMD5: http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php

Here is my code :

```
  def MD5HashDirectory(String fileDir) {
    MD5 md5 = new MD5();
    new File(fileDir).eachFileRecurse{ file ->
      if (file.isFile()) {
        String hashFile = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(new File(file.path)));
        md5.Update(hashFile, null);
      }

    }
    String hashFolder = md5.asHex();
    return hashFolder
  }
```

Comment: With groovy (probably also in Java), it can be useful to use Ant (or better Gant). See : http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html

Comment: That's actually hashing the hashes of the contents of the files, rather than just hashing the contents.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same requirement and chose my 'directory hash' to be an MD5 hash of the concatenated streams of all (non-directory) files within the directory. As crozin mentioned in comments on [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169137), you can use `SequenceInputStream` to act as a stream concatenating a load of other streams. I'm using [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec) for the MD5 algorithm.

Basically, you recurse through the directory tree, adding `FileInputStream` instances to a `Vector` for non-directory files. `Vector` then conveniently has the `elements()` method to provide the `Enumeration` that `SequenceInputStream` needs to loop through. To the MD5 algorithm, this just appears as one `InputStream`.

A gotcha is that you need the files presented in the same order every time for the hash to be the same with the same inputs. The `listFiles()` method in `File` doesn't guarantee an ordering, so I sort by filename.

I was doing this for SVN controlled files, and wanted to avoid hashing the hidden SVN files, so I implemented a flag to avoid hidden files.

The relevant basic code is as below. (Obviously it could be 'hardened'.)

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public String calcMD5HashForDir(File dirToHash, boolean includeHiddenFiles) {

    assert (dirToHash.isDirectory());
    Vector<FileInputStream> fileStreams = new Vector<FileInputStream>();

    System.out.println("Found files for hashing:");
    collectInputStreams(dirToHash, fileStreams, includeHiddenFiles);

    SequenceInputStream seqStream = 
            new SequenceInputStream(fileStreams.elements());

    try {
        String md5Hash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(seqStream);
        seqStream.close();
        return md5Hash;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error reading files to hash in "
                                   + dirToHash.getAbsolutePath(), e);
    }

}

private void collectInputStreams(File dir,
                                 List<FileInputStream> foundStreams,
                                 boolean includeHiddenFiles) {

    File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();        
    Arrays.sort(fileList,               // Need in reproducible order
                new Comparator<File>() {
                    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {                       
                        return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
                    }
                });

    for (File f : fileList) {
        if (!includeHiddenFiles && f.getName().startsWith(".")) {
            // Skip it
        }
        else if (f.isDirectory()) {
            collectInputStreams(f, foundStreams, includeHiddenFiles);
        }
        else {
            try {
                System.out.println("\t" + f.getAbsolutePath());
                foundStreams.add(new FileInputStream(f));
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e.getMessage()
                            + ": file should never not be found!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer - I decided to use your code. Note though that it is not portable - checking for hidden files should be based on "isHidden", not on the file name. In some cases it is probably best to check both as some programs (e.g. Eclipse) save work files starting with a dot (e.g. .classpath) without making them hidden on non-Unix OS.

Comment: @OmriSpector Yes, good point re the non-portability and glad you found the snippet useful. That bit was quick and dirty code; I did say "Obviously it could be 'hardened'" :-)

Comment: The answer is awesome, but it misses if file names are changed, retaining alphabetical order, so we can take one more hash with absolute path of file.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Stuart Rossiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15503271/3764804)'s answer but clean code and hidden files properly handled:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Hashing {
    public static String hashDirectory(String directoryPath, boolean includeHiddenFiles) throws IOException {
        File directory = new File(directoryPath);
        
        if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a directory");
        }

        Vector<FileInputStream> fileStreams = new Vector<>();
        collectFiles(directory, fileStreams, includeHiddenFiles);

        try (SequenceInputStream sequenceInputStream = new SequenceInputStream(fileStreams.elements())) {
            return DigestUtils.md5Hex(sequenceInputStream);
        }
    }

    private static void collectFiles(File directory, List<FileInputStream> fileInputStreams,
                                     boolean includeHiddenFiles) throws IOException {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        if (files != null) {
            Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparing(File::getName));

            for (File file : files) {
                if (includeHiddenFiles || !Files.isHidden(file.toPath())) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        collectFiles(file, fileInputStreams, includeHiddenFiles);
                    } else {
                        fileInputStreams.add(new FileInputStream(file));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

HashCopy is a Java application. It can generate and verify MD5 and SHA on a single file or a directory recursively. I am not sure if it has an API. It can be downloaded from www.jdxsoftware.org.

Comment: Nice app, but a license is required if HashCopy is used for commercial purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this in a Gradle build file, it's much simpler than with plain Groovy.

Here's an example:

```
def sources = fileTree('rootDir').matching {
    include 'src/*', 'build.gradle'
}.sort { it.name }
def digest = MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA-1')
sources.each { digest.update(it.bytes) }
digest.digest().encodeHex().toString()
```

`MessageDigest` is from the Java std lib: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Algorithms supported in all JVMs are:

```
MD5
SHA-1
SHA-256
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what it means to take the md5sum of a directory. You might want the checksum of the file listing; you might want the checksum of the file listings and their contents. If you're already summing the file data themselves, I'd suggest you spec an unambiguous representation for a directory listing (watch out for evil characters in filenames), then compute and hash that each time. You also need to consider how you will handle special files (sockets, pipes, devices and symlinks in the unix world; NTFS has file streams and I believe something akin to symlinks as well).

Answer (score 1):

I calculated sha512 instead of md5 (since its more secure) but the idea is you can define this in your gradle file or in raw groovy.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.io.File

def calcDirHash(fileDir) {
  def hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512")
  new File(fileDir).eachFileRecurse{ file ->
    if (file.isFile()) {
      file.eachByte 4096, {bytes, size ->
        hash.update(bytes, 0, size);
      }
    }
  }
  return hash.digest().encodeHex()
}
```

Then call calcDirHash in any task (and pass in the directory you want hashed).

You can use other encoding schemes instead of SHA-512.