# java hash a folder

Tags: java, hash, md5, sha1

Does anyone have any idea about how to hash a folder in java using sha1 or md5?
I have several files in one folder, and I need a hash for all of them.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean separate hash values for each individual file, or a single hash value of all the files concatenated together?

Comment: @Xuanzi Han: You'll want to {SHA-1,MD5} all the files in your folder and then XOR all the cryptographic hashes together into one final hash.

Comment: @Wyzard: concatenating all the files together before producing a final hash may be harder to reproduce than XOR'ing the individual hashes.  If you concatenate then hash you would have to make sure to concatenate files in the same order everytime you "hash" the folder.

Comment: user988052: You could also sort that hashes and then concatenate them, which might be more secure cryptographically.

Comment: @XuanziHan: Please, specify what do you mean by "hash a folder". A folder itself doesn't have any content that could be hashed. If you want to create a hash of the content of all files from within a folder how would you like to do that? Treat all files as a single one? Use `SequenceInputStream`. Maybe you want to hash each file and the combine all of those hashes? How those hashes should be combined? Should they be concated or maybe XOR-ed? In other words... be more specific.