# java checksum directory

Tags: java, validation, file-io, directory

I'm trying to figure out conceptually what approach to take when trying to verify the transfer of directory structure from source to a target.  Functional example, I want to move /usr/mystuff to some network server ///usr/mystuff (doesn't necessarily have to be a network transfer).  So the problem i'm faced with is validating that the target is exactly of the same structure, files, etc as the source.

I've been researching this for a while and i'm trying to come up with 'the best approach' my thought so far is...

1) Zip Dir Tree, MD5 Zip.   File io copy directory structure to new location, Zip that, MD5 new zip, compare MD5 of source and target.  this seems cumbersome, and probably not efficient.

I dont' need any coding examples, i'm just looking for some input on how you'd accomplish the validation of the structure being the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The method of zip, checksum - transfer - checksum verify does not seem to be cumbersome.

Comment: I suppose you need to do this from a java program, correct?

Comment: @user503413 that is the approach i'm taking or attempting to take

Comment: please check the response I pointed you too.

Answer (score 0):

I find "checksum" tasks in ant builds very useful...

...

```
<checksum todir="${basedir}/md5">
<fileset dir="${remotedir}">
    <include name="**/**/**"/>
    <exclude name="md5/**"/>
    <exclude name="reports*.xml"/>
    <exclude name="user/*.*"/>
    <exclude name="temp/*.*"/>
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/lib/test.jar"/>  
    </fileset>
</checksum>
```

...

See documentation here

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/checksum.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds rather similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010071/how-to-calculate-md5-checksum-on-directory-with-java-or-groovy?rq=1) one. Zipping and computing the MD5 sounds like a costly operation.